# VPN Incoming Ports

Tags: vpn, ports

For the past few years, I have been stuck with mobile broadband connections, which block all incoming traffic for all ports. This has made it impossible for me to do things like play multiplayer games or even allow co-workers to access my computer's web server.

I had heard about VPNs before, but today I found out that you can get a VPN with a dedicated IP and have all incoming ports open for that IP (tuvpn does it, for example). However, I have no experience with VPNs, or how this would work.

If I did that, would that mean that accessing that dedicated IP would be the same as accessing my computer? Would this mean that if people typed that IP address into their browser, they'd finally be able to access my computer's web server?

Or have I misunderstood something? How does it really work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I did that, would that mean that accessing that dedicated IP would be the same as accessing my computer? Would this mean that if people typed that IP address into their browser, they'd finally be able to access my computer's web server?

Yes, as long as the computer is connected to the VPN.

Comment: That is astounding! VPN really seems like an incredible thing. :D